# Cannot change primary key (AKA Auto increment) to User ID rather than Username

Tags: php, authentication, registration

I recently got a registration/login script from JPMaster77. All in all it works great and I got the script to work, but when I add in a new column in a table as "ID" and change it to primary key the script gets weird.

Here is the SQL I use

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 id int(11) primary key,
 username varchar(30),
 password varchar(32),
 userid varchar(32),
 userlevel tinyint(1) unsigned not null,
 email varchar(50),
 timestamp int(11) unsigned not null
);
```

As you can see it actually works good, until you see the registration code. The error "We're sorry, but an error has occurred and your registration for the username test, could not be completed.
Please try again at a later time." pops up everytime anyone tries to register and I believe it is for this reason. I have been trying to fix this for a while, but I am not familiar with Primary Key's and Autoincrements. The script is kind of long so I felt like posting it on Pastebin rather than writing it all here. http://pastebin.com/DYRCp3Sc

Comment: The table looks okay, have you debugged your code to the point where you're sure that it's the database, and not your query?

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't see the auto_increment column at all in sql script. if you required it then your table create query should be like that

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 id int(11) primary key auto_increment  ,
 username varchar(30),
 password varchar(32),
 userid varchar(32),
 userlevel tinyint(1) unsigned not null,
 email varchar(50),
 timestamp int(11) unsigned not null
);
```

Without auto_increment You need to insert unique primary key generated by you/application. MySQL will not insert any value. Also mysql may gave error on insertion.

Comment: Well that actually did fix that part, I understand the differences of Primary and auto_Increment (One must be Primary to have auto_increment), but I still can't figure out why my code is not registering me.

Comment: As I previously say, MySQL will not insert any value for primary key column if you have not defined the auto_increment. So let you do not set any value for ID column, Then primary key will throw error as it will not allow null and duplicate values (in case 0 is allowed).

Comment: Well it is defined as AI.. As for primary key not allowing it be null, i believe it isn't null already.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the code that actually invoke registration function. But it seems the table is okey. Have you tried to insert data into this table by console? Tried to input the same data, that you are entering in your form and see what will be.

Comment: Well I had it in the pastebin under "session.php" but I believe I found it, it is somewhere In here I think: http://pastebin.com/a1u01ZqR

Comment: What debug tool do you use? Try to change the userId string in this call $database->updateUserField($this->username, "userid", $this->userid); to just "id". And in general have a close look at this method, maybe something wrong is going there.

Comment: userid and id are 2 different things, are you sure about this? Edit: Just tried and didn't work. Man this is frustrating. I have spent a while looking through trying to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

when you want to insert a new record and you have id primary key and auto_increment
**try this :**

```
insert into users (username,password,userid,userlevel,email,timestamp) values
('username','password','userid','userlevel','email','timestamp');
```

you omit field id, because it is auto incremented, make this modification where you are inserting
into the table in your script